# SQL Server Stored Proc takes (much) longer to run than the same query executed from text in Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

So here is a bit of a strange one...
I have a stored proc that takes 40 seconds to run.
I copy the contents of the stored proc to a new query window, change the 2 input parameters (which are both dates) so they are declared and set, and run the query. It is basically instant, sub 1 second execution.
The only difference is the stored proc takes the 2 dates as parameters.

Anyone got any idea what can make that happen?

(I am running SQL Server 2005)

Comment: btw, I have tried marking the proc for recompilation, it had no effect

Comment: http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Recompilation sniffs the parameters, so it can make no difference.

[This article explains my statement](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/sql/2005/recomp.mspx#E6TAE)...

> ...parameter values are sniffed during
>   compilation or recompilation...

You need to mask the parameters:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [uspFoo]
    @Date1 datetime,
    @Date2 datetime
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @IDate1 datetime, @IDate2 datetime;
    SELECT @IDate1 = @Date1, @IDate2 = @Date2;
    -- Stuff here that depends on @IDate1 and @IDate2
END
```

Comment: +1 I know this is an old post but you just saved me trying to work this one out!

Answer (score 5):

As gbn says, this is a parameter sniffing issue. An alternative way to his suggestion is to include the following line at the end of your query:

```
OPTION (RECOMPILE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Run the profiler and capture the query plans for the execution.  Check to see what the differences are - you may be able to tune the query or force a particular plan.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and found it was caused because I was setting up the parameter as a DATE but the column it was being compared against in the WHERE clause was in DATETIME so it was like SSMS was converting the data type for every row it was comparing. Changing the parameter data type to DATETIME or masking the parameter as mentioned above resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

had a same issue, I tried to resolve Parameter sniffing and also used recompile options but didn't work for me.. then came to know that adding ASSUME_MIN_SELECTIVITY_FOR_FILTER_ESTIMATES in the update query can resolve my problem..